# How to mock only one constant exported from a config file with many constants using Jest

Tags: jestjs, mocking

I have a config file with simplified content (it contains several more constants) like this:

```
export const appTitle = "Drzewo wyboru"

export const warnings ={
missing:" Kryterium"
duplicate: "Duplikacja"
```

In a test file I have written a mock like this:

```
jest.mock('../../../src/config',()=>({AppTitle:'abc123test'}));
```

The problem is that other items in the config file are necessary to correctly render the tested component as well - so this mock breaks a test.

I have read about possible uses of `jest.requireActual` but it works with objects and in config I have loose items.

How could I mock only this one item, leaving the rest intact without changing the structure of my config file?

Comment: I'd suggest you _don't_. Why are you trying to mock data?

Answer (score 1):

You can do partial mocking for your module:

```
jest.mock('../../../src/config',() => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('../../../src/config');
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    AppTitle: 'abc123test',
  };
});
```

More information can be found in the official doc [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-partials).

(Your example states that you want to mock out `AppTitle`, yet the actual module contains `appTitle` which is a different property, I am not sure if this was a mistake, but if it was I can update my answer)